# Including bibtex within a single Rmarkdown file?

Tags: r-markdown, bibliography

Suppose you want to make a (truly) "stand-alone" reproducible Rmarkdown file that can be run independently, and you have citations in the text.

One way of doing it, that I've tried once for a similar issue (model definition of JAGS models), is to include the content of `.bib` file in a chunk and write them to a file using, e.g., `writeLines()`, and adding `bibliography: ref.bib` to the YAML.

Is there a (neater) way of doing it without producing the `.bib` file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can include refernces in the YAML header, c.f. https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#citations

Comment: Thanks @RalfStubner. But it needs a reformatting of the references from `bib` to the YAML-friendly syntax, right?

Comment: Yes, the references have to be reformatted. You can use `pandoc-citeproc --bib2yaml` for that task.